# How do people determine initial ratio of the parent nuclide and daughter product in radiometric dating?

Tags: geology, geophysics, radioactivity

I understand that we have zircon crystals that prevent entering or leaving of nuclide or lead after forming. But how cand we understand what was the initial ratio?

Comment: As you said, in the case of zircon it doesn't matter. For other methods (Rb-Sr, Sm-Nd), we use an [isochron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isochron_dating).